# WebStorm language injection for inline css within JS via */css*/`.styles{}`

Tags: webstorm

I am trying to achieve the following behaviour in WebStorm:
https://github.com/bashmish/es6-string-css

I believe I can do this using language injection.
I have a TypeScript file with embedded css

```
const styles = */css*/`
    .style {
        color: red;
    }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

`*/css*/` is not a valid Typescript syntax... For tagged templates like:

```
const styles = css`
    .style {
        color: red;
    }
`
```

you can easily create language injections in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections**.

In 2019.2, it should be an injection of *JS Tagged Literal Injection* type, like:

[image]

for previous versions, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22106#focus=streamItem-27-2451611.0-0